# Why can't I change the color of the titlebar of Ambiance?

Tags: themes, metacity, ambiance

When I change the color for highlighted menu-entries for clearlook the window border is affected, too. This isn't the case with Ambiance or Radiance. Why? Is it a bug or intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. Some Metacity themes (like Clearlooks) use the colors set by the user, while other themes (like Ambiance and Radiance) hardcode the colors used. If you want to change the colors, you'll have to manually edit them.

- [Tutorial on Designing Metacity Themes](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/MetacityThemes)

Comment: But why are they hardcoded?

Comment: @Toxicbits - Probably for several reasons, 1) If you want to make the color of the titlebar very different than the color of highlighted menu entries (which it is in Ambiance and Radiance) and 2) It's a lot easier to just hardcode the colors.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks (some nonsense so I can submit my comment)

Comment: @toxicbits: I bet it is to be able to fallback to a always working theme.